# Tensorflow/Keras - ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run some machine learning examples so am importing some packages

```
sklearn version 0.22.1
tensorflow version  2.3.0
keras version 2.3.0
```

in the following way:

```
import os
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlip.pyplot as plt
```

I am getting the import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence'
```

Full traceback:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import callbacks

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .callbacks import Callback

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..engine.training_utils import standardize_input_data

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils import Sequence

ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence'
```

I have looked online for help and tried a few different Tensorflow and keras versions. I have also tried `import tensorflow.keras as keras` and `import tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence` without success.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow/keras?

Comment: yes - I have tried various version of both - is there a version of each you would suggest?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using tf 2.9?

Comment: (1). DON'T mix old keras with new keras. in same environment (2). As you're using tf > 2.0, then import keras from tensorflow. i.e. `from tensorflow.keras import LSTM`.

Comment: Which python version are you using? Have you tried running the above code using the latest TensorFlow version?